# Regex for filtering keywords from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying JS regX to match some values and replace them with the markup. So here is the code I tried.

```
content = '<p>[dfp:advertisement:leaderboard:750x90]</p>text here<p>[dfp:advertisement:box1:300x250]</p>';
var regX = /([a-zA-Z0-9]*):([0-9]*x[0-9]*)/g;
match = regX.exec(content);
```

Okay, the issue is this will only match the first value, not the second one. I've added `/g` but no luck yet.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: The second time you got multiple `:`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single call to `exec` will only return the *first* match, even with the `g` flag. But the regex will contain state such that subsequent multiple calls to `exec` using the same regex will return the following matching items.

From the MDN [`exec` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured
>
> [ ... ]
>
> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.

So this code will `alert` the first two matches from your example:

```
var content = '<p>[dfp:advertisement:leaderboard:750x90]</p>text here<p>[dfp:advertisement:box1:300x250]</p>';

var regX = /([a-zA-Z0-9]*):([0-9]*x[0-9]*)/g;
var match = regX.exec(content);
var match2 = regX.exec(content);

alert(match[0]);
alert(match2[0]);
```

As others have already mentioned, you can instead use `match` on a string to return an array with the multiple matches.

So, similar to the above code, this code will `alert` the first two matches from your example:

```
var content = '<p>[dfp:advertisement:leaderboard:750x90]</p>text here<p>[dfp:advertisement:box1:300x250]</p>';
var regX = /([a-zA-Z0-9]*):([0-9]*x[0-9]*)/g;

var match = content.match(regX);

alert(match[0]);
alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `content.match` instead of `regX.exec`